# How to change the background/text color of a layout when daynight theme is used

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm using Theme.AppCompat.DayNight and I want to customize a certain layout background and text color to change depending on whether it's day or night mode .

Here's what I tried so far:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryDarkColorAmber</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColorAmber</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primaryDarkColorAmber</item>
</style>

<style name="PopUpTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <!-- layout custom theme there's no darkBackground value...!! -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/popup_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "day or night mode". Do you mean it is dark or your app is in night mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first of all create res/values-night this directory then add same as res/value file you can copy and replace to color and after that when you change day or night theme you can get color according to your style

Comment: you can use this link :-https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94

Comment: Crappy thing to do. Most of the time developers will forget to add corresponding color

Answer (score 5):

If you are following Android's [Color theming System](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/color/), then you can use:

```
<View
...
android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
.../>
```

Similarly, for texts you can use `?android:attr/textColorPrimary` and for icons `?attr/colorControlNormal`. This way you do not need to create separate value files.

You can find more details [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme).

Comment: Thanks for that. I've been having transparent background fragments with the previous fragment showing underneath and ive been struggling to get a background color that works for both day and night, this did the trick.